# Question regarding fundemental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Hi consider the following expression:

$F(x)=\int_a^{x}f(t)(x-t)dt$ and hence determine $F'(x)$.

This is what I have I done: first split into

$F(x)=\int_a^{x}xf(t)dt$ - $\int_a^{x}tf(t)dt$

The second half of the expression is integral of an expression fully interms of t, hence I know by the fundemental theorem of calculus upon differentiating it i can rewrite it as $xf(x)$.

However I have problem getting past the first half $\int_a^{x}xf(t)dt$ it is an integral containing x and t. is there any technique that I can apply in order to evaluate this integral?

Answer (score 2):

Write $\int_a^xxf(t)dt=x\int_a^xf(t)dt$. $G(x)=x, H(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt, x\int_a^xf(t)dt=G(x)H(x), (G(x)H(x))'=G(x)H'(x)+G'(x)H(x) =xf(x)+\int_a^xf(t)dt$

Comment: Oh my! i cnt believe i didnt thought of that. thank u soo much